# Check if String only contains these characters {([])}

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method that checks if a given string **only** contains these {([])} characters.

```
// Test strings
String S = "{U}"  // should give FALSE
String S = "[U]"  // should give FALSE
String S = "U"  // should give FALSE
String S = "([)()]" // should give TRUE
```

I've tried:

```
    if(S.matches("[{(\\[\\])}]")) {
        return 1;
    }
```

But this returns never true.

Comment: can't return `true` if you return `1`. Should they always be in that exact order or can they be at any position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.matches()` matches the *entire* string against the pattern. The pattern you are trying is failing because it only matches a single character - for example, `"{".matches("[{(\\[\\])}]")` would return true. You need to add a repeat to your regex - either `*` if you want to match empty strings, or `+` if the string must contain at least one character, like so:

```
if(S.matches("[{(\\[\\])}]+")) {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(S.matches("^[{(\\[\\])}]+$")) {
    return 1;
}
```

`^` - beginning of the line

`[]+` - characters contained in character class `[]` ONE OR MORE times

`$` - end of the line

---

If you want to create a **method** (as you've mentioned in question), you might want to consider creating such method returning `boolean` (note that returning `boolean` (`true` or `false`) is not equal to returning `1` or `0` in Java):

```
public boolean checkIfContainsOnlyParenthesis(String input) {
    return input.matches("^[{(\\[\\])}]+$");
}
```

If your intention was to return `1` when condition is fulfilled and - for example - `0`, when it's not, you need to change return value of that method to`int`:

```
public int checkIfContainsOnlyParenthesis(String input) {
    if(input.matches("^[{(\\[\\])}]+$")) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

That way you can pass your `S` string as argument of that method like this:

```
checkIfContainsOnlyParenthesis(S);
```